# How can Harmonic Convergence influence bending in Season 3?

Tags: the-legend-of-korra

In Season 3, after Harmonic Convergence, it seems that somehow it

> made new airbenders all around the world.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

The newsreel introduction to S3E7 stated that the Harmonic Convergence caused an energy shift, which is the cause of the new Airbenders. I think that's as close to an explanation as we've gotten.

We know from the *Avatar: The Last Airbender* finale and the *Legend of Korra* episodes *Beginnings* that energy bending can grant bending.  Seems like the Harmonic Convergence's energy resulted in similar energy bending in random people around the world.